# ios swift did select row to check the string equal is not working

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Here my code :

```
    @IBOutlet weak var billSelectorBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var optionListTB: UITableView!
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return optionsListNames.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = optionsListNames[indexPath.row] as? String
         return cell

    }

    private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let selectedItem = optionsListNames.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSString

        billSelectorBtn.setTitle(selectedItem as String, for: UIControlState.normal)

        if selectedItem .isEqual(to: "Current Bill")
        {

            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }

        else if selectedItem .isEqual(to: "Water Bill")
        {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }

            optionListTB.isHidden = true
    }
```

So in my `didselectrow method` i am check whether the selected string is equal.And if its equal i will keep the ui as some color chnage. But its not working ??

i saw this tutorial : http://www.aegisiscblog.com/how-to-implement-custom-dropdown-list-in-swift.html

please help me out..

Thanks

Comment: What do you meann by "string equal is not working"

Comment: @Maddy   i am checking whether i selected value from my drop down list is equal with my array data ...you can check that tutorial link that i have posted

Comment: Why your tableView method is private?

Comment: r u using storyboard

Comment: @Raymond  i tried to remove that also..but it din work!!

Comment: @Maddy  yes i am using storyboard...i did that delagate, datasource and all

Comment: @Raymond   any solution will be help full

Comment: @hybridDev check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called)

Comment: I think you are missing `tableView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @JožeWs   no i have added ..still not able to solve

Comment: @Raymond  can u help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222202/ionic-3-app-size-is-more-than-30-mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tableview` default color is white that you added in storyboard. To match `tableview` color to its background view you have to clear the `tableview` color and vice versa for the `Uitableviewcell`.

In your `viewdidload` add this line,

```
tableview.backgroundColor =     UIColor.clear //tableview is your tableview outlet
```

And in `cellForRowAt indexPath`

Add,

```
  cell.backgroundColor =     UIColor.clear
```

In swift 3 `didselect` syntax has been changed to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    }
```

Comment: i am not getting you.. my did select only not working....you these code in my others function ????

Comment: see in my did select , if i select any option from table view..it have to display as my button name right ??..that only coded there... but ist not working in my screen...and also no bg color chnaging

Comment: you have to clear tableview color so when you change the `self.view` background color on `didselect` the other color will automatically change to that one as those will be transparent

Comment: just add this code first if u did not get your desired result then we will proceed further

Comment: i did get this work,,,and then only i explained the problem niw

Comment: no , still same thing...if i select any option from my table view...ist not showing as my button title, and table view also not hidden, and no view colr changing...it seems like no entry to my did select fuction

Comment: i tried your solution..but it din work.... My first problem is that did select function is not at all calling...i checked like this ` func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        print("did seelct pressed") }`

Comment: Ok seems the issue is in the method name its not swift 3 function name. Its swift 2.

Comment: @Maddy   can u help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222202/ionic-3-app-size-is-more-than-30-mb

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `isEqual`, use "**==**" to compare strings. And make your `tableView`'s backgroundColor and cell's backgroundColor to clear to see the color change, if you have your tableView occupy fullscreen.

Comment: i tried your solution..but it din work.... My first problem is that did select function is not at all calling...i checked like this ` func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        print("did seelct pressed") }`

Comment: Did you make your viewController conform to these protocols: `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource` ?

Comment: can u help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222202/ionic-3-app-size-is-more-than-30-mb

Answer (score 0):

Remove `private` from your delegate method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    /// add implementation
}
```

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154525/why-delegate-methods-needs-to-be-public-in-swift)