# ionic 3 app size is more than 30 mb

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 new. When i check my app size is more than 30 mb. i removed my all assets... But still i dont know how this much app size is coming.

And this is my folder of my project:
[image]

```
Node Module = 178mb
resource = 1.2 mb
src= 2.3 mb
www= 14 mb
platform= 468 mb
plugins = 7.8 mb
```

So in my platform folder i saw more mb. So here inside my Plugin folder images:

Platform --> Android -->
[image]

```
Asssets :14 mb
cordova :3.3 mb
cordova plugin-croswalk: 6 kb
cordovalib:1.3 mb
gradle:56 kb
libs: 2kb
platform_www: 100kb
res: 300kb
src: 200kb
build: 444MB
```

So inside build:
[image]

```
Generated: 60kb
intermediates: 376 mb
output: 30mb
tmp:0kb
```

i tried deleting this `intermediates` and i build it again.. still it automatically shows up..

Please help me , with in two days i need to ship my app.. But my app is very small. its not more than 10 mb...But i dont know 30 mb..

please any on know help me out..

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391023/71mb-added-to-app-size-for-crosswalk

Comment: @Maddy   i remove that using this command `cordova plugin remove crosswalk-webview`   but my app show only white screen

Comment: @Maddy   i thought to use crowswalk lite..but how can i install that ??

Comment: What command are you using to build it?

Comment: @rory_za`sudo cordova build android` i am using ionic 3

Comment: Add a `--prod` on there and check file size?

Comment: @Maddy  CAN you please help me on this...i removed that crosswalk plugin...but in my app only white screen are showing..should i need to add that plugin again ???..then how can i reduce my app size.....its  very urgent for me...now...please help me

Comment: @hybridDev Crosswalk will make your app bigger in size because it will add the chromium browser in your app. This is to ensure that all android versions will run on chromium and not on their native browsers.

Comment: @hybridDev i would suggest that you keep Crosswalk as it is, without it, developing a hybrid app can be a nightmare

Comment: @Akis   then my app size is more than 30 mb....what should i need to do now ??

Comment: @hybridDev is there a problem if the size is 30mb? I dont get it

Comment: @Akis   you said we have to use crosswalk...but if i use that my app size is 30 mb....in my app i have only 3 screens with no image........it have to be 3 mb only....i checked by remove that plugin........but if i use that crosswalk plugin...my app size is 30 mb......so how can i reduce my app size with using my crosswalk plugin

Comment: @hybridDev you cant

Comment: then wat is in use of making app for user with 30 mb...